# Line breaks in CSS pseudo elements using attribute selector

Tags: html, css, attributes, pseudo-element

So I've been trying to get a line break in an after element and I've ran into (what I think) is an interesting quirk.

```
#fourth figcaption:before
{
   content: 'Figure \A' attr(title) ' ';
   white-space: pre-wrap;  
}
```

This works how I'd like and I get a line break before the content from the attribute.

How ever when I go to get the content entirely from the attr the line breaks stop rendering.

```
#fifth figcaption:before
{
   content: attr(title);
   white-space: pre-wrap;  
}
```

You can see this here > http://jsbin.com/huyaxifomo/edit?html,css,output

Does anyone know why this would make a difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but am not quite getting the issue here, if I replace `white-space` with `display: block;`, it works as expected

Comment: I think I've linked to the wrong fiddle. Hold on a sec.

Comment: I've linked to the correct demo now.

Comment: Oh got it, your expectations are incorrect. For CSS, whatever value it gets from the attribute is just a static value. You cannot parse that string by using `attr()` only. So if you use `\a \A`, it will print as a literal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `\A` or `\a` or anything similar as a value to your HTML attribute is just a static value. Using something like following in your CSS will not parse such syntax for your `content` property

```
<div data-stuff="Hello \a World"></div>
```

And CSS like

```
content: attr(title); 
/* 
   This will not parse \a as a line break and would rather treat it as 
   a string.
*/
```

If you want to add line breaks from CSS, you need to declare `\A` in your stylesheet and not the HTML attribute. Hence, something like

```
content: attr(title) '\A World'; /* works now, as your \A will be parsed by CSS */
```

Comment: What other stuff I can use in CSS content like making something Bold or shorter etc?